# Downloading file with http

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to download a pdf file from a link using the following code. However, I got 404 error page. The same link just work fine in browser. What would be the cause?

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'www.xxxx.xxx',
  path: '/achieved/a1.pdf'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';
 //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
  str += chunk;
});

//the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: Not seeing your URL in that code, but try a wget for that URL. If it works, hardcode it as string in your code (in the request call), see if that works. If it does, then whatever handlers your url-containing-variable is mangling the URL

Comment: I did hardcode approach, but still what I get is 404 response page instead of the file.

Comment: so let's simplify: install the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) module, `var request = require("request")` it, and try a `request(your_url, function(err, res, body) { ... });` and see what it does.